# raspberry pi booting failed on custom kernel

Tags: boot, cross-compilation, linux, kernel

hello I have compiled my custom kernel and pack initramfs into it. I have created two partition **fat32** and **ext3**. fat32 contains bootloaders and kernel and ext3 contains rootfs. I have made a raw disk image on that. But when I try this on qemu it's show init script not found.

### Here is the screenshot.

[image]

### here is my init script

`!/bin/busybox sh`

rescue_shell() {
    echo "Something went wrong. Dropping you to a shell."
    busybox --install -s
    exec /bin/sh
}

mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
echo "This script mounts rootfs and boots it up, nothing more!"
mount -o ro /dev/sda2 /mnt/root || rescue_shell
umount /proc
umount /sys
exec switch_root /mnt/root /sbin/init

#### I have put the init script on initramfs with

```
chmod +x init
```

#### I am using qemu with the follwing parameter

```
qemu-system-arm.exe -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -hda my_custom_image.img -kernel kernel-qemu -m 256 -append "root=/dev/sda2"
```

#### Here is my initramfs structure

`.:             directory

./etc:         directory

./mnt:         directory

./mnt/root:    directory

./dev:         directory

./dev/sda2:    block special

./dev/null:    character special

./dev/console: character special

./dev/tty:     character special

./dev/sda1:    block special

./lib:         directory

./bin:         directory

./bin/busybox: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, stripped

./root:        directory

./sbin:        directory

./sys:         directory

./proc:        directory`

And my rootfs contains also the same structure. **Is there anything wrong what I have done so far?**.

And Another thing when my same structure is in physical raspberry the init script got error and entering in rescue mode with the following error.

```
kernel panic not syncing attempted kill init
```

Can any one show me a proper guidance. I can't find a way out.

If additional details require I will surely provide.
**Thank You**.

Comment: You might struggle to get an answer here. Besides the information you provided is very limited and the errors are to generic. You need to go knee deep in debug or go ask in a Linux SE?

Comment: @ppumkin do you need any further information? I am tired to get a solution

Comment: No sorry- I have no idea about compiling kernels. It was always regarded as the most complicated thing to do with Linux.(for a beginner and even intermediate user)

Comment: My guess is that `devtmpfs: error mounting -2` is a possible indication of your problem, as I get `devtmpfs: initialized` when RaspBMC boots on my Pi.  Can Linux run without a tmp fs?  Could be just noise though ...

Comment: Thank you for your information. Possibly the error occurring either for **initramfs directory structure**, mainly for the **devices** or **kernel configuration with devtmpfs support.** Let me check with all possibilities. I will surely answer it if I would find a way.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn yes linux can run without devtmpfs in that case you need to add proper devices in /dev which reside in initramfs.

Comment: I would guess that your `busybox` executable is compiled for a different architecture. Did you build it with the same headers as you built the kernel?

Comment: yes I have cross compiled it for arm.

Comment: Are you missing a hashtag character '"x"' at the beginning of your `init` file?  You have `!/bin/busybox sh` posted instead of `#!/bin/busybox sh`, or is that just a typo?

Comment: no no, # is the formatting character so have just ignore it for this post

Comment: @ShantanuBanerjee Are you missing `initrd` parameter in qemu command ? I tried following tutorial http://confoundedtech.blogspot.in/2012/04/raspberry-pi-virtualise-rpi-debian.html and it is working. This might help you.

Comment: @AbhijeetKasurde dear avijit, I am using built in `initramfs` into `kernel` so I don't need to pass it over qemu.

Comment: @AwesomeUser Qemu kernel was an error, burn your image in SD card and try it directly with Raspberry PI